# Word Spaces rather than Character Spaces in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to control size of spaces in between words in MS Word (text alignment is not the issue as it may be default left aligned).

I've tried to search it over the internet and on Stack Exchange as well. But everyone is telling about `Font (Dialogue) > Advanced (Tab) > Spacing`. which controls spacing between characters rather than between words. Character Spacing Option is available but word spacing option is not available.

[image: Character Spacing Option is available but word spacing option is not available.]

Comment: As a workaround, you could replace all space characters with an *en space* ( ) or an *em space*: ( ), see here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2002/index.htm and here https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2003/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Space size is inherent to the font as a font contains a character that is used to represent space. In order to change the size of a space you either need to change its font size or use a different font. Wingdings for example seems to have rather big spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the **Spacing** settings on the **Advanced** tab of the **Font** dialog box. Just apply them to the spaces between words instead of the words themselves.

To make this change to all spaces in the whole document or a selected section of it, you can use the **Find and Replace** dialog box. On the **Replace** tab, type a space in both the **Find what** and **Replace with** fields. Then, while the cursor is still in the **Replace with** field, click **More >>**, select **Format** > **Font**, and then, on the **Advanced** tab, set the **Spacing** and **By** fields.

Or, if you need to make the change more selectively, you could create a character style for it, and apply that style only to the spaces that need more space.